# Don't post or draft if post already exists

Tags: posts, draft

I've got a problem. I don't want duplicate posts. Any way to check if a post already exists and if it does just set the new one to draft? I am using IFTTT to update my blog and sometimes it posts multiple times.

Comment: What is "IFTTT"?

Comment: [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/wtf) is a social media helper site, "If This, Then That." It allows you to set up internet actions based on triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what IFTTT is but you can use the `save_post` action hook to do a check for duplicate posts. This hook runs whenever a post is created or updated you would then be able to right your own code to check against existing posts.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post